# Installing APCU for PHP 7 on windows server 2016

Tags: apcu

i am using xampp 3.2.2 and i want to install Installing APCU for PHP 7 on windows server 2016 . i have tried a number of things and am still not getting any APC configuration information in my phpinfo page.